# How can I prevent url re-writing in EventStore using Docker?

Tags: docker, eventstoredb

I'm trying to run a server (EventStore) in a Docker, in this case their own image.  I'm running this image with the -P flag to assign external ports.  (My usage makes specific port assignment impractical.)

When I start up EventStore's image, port 2113 (their web port) is mapped to some high port, like 33125.  If I enter (my_ip):33125 in my browser, it gets rewritten to something like (my_ip):2113/web/.  Of course, outside the Docker port 2113 means nothing!

How can I prevent this re-writing, or at least contain it all inside the Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have faced a know issue. The [docs says](https://hub.docker.com/r/eventstore/eventstore/):

> Note : The admin UI and atom feeds will only work if you publish the node's http port to a matching port on the host. (i.e. you need to run the container with `-p 2113:2113`)

And this is the opened issue regarding that:

https://github.com/EventStore/eventstore-docker/issues/6

It seems that is an internal check that EventStore does, so it's very difficult to solve from outside the server code.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to set the `EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT` environment variable to tell eventstore how the port mapping is done. For example if `EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT` has value `52040`, then the port mapping should be `-p 52040:2113`.

You can find more information through the documentation of eventstore:
https://eventstore.com/docs/server/command-line-arguments/#interface-options

I tested it with `docker run eventstore/eventstore -e EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT=52040 -p 52040:2113` and was able to reach the interface through port `52040`.